# Stream music from XBMC to iTunes over local network

Tags: macos, audio, streaming, kodi, audio-streaming

I'm looking for a simple way to get iTunes to either:

- See a remote directory as part of its library. I store my music on my server (locally), but would want to listen to it from my mac through iTunes.
- Find a way for XBMC to stream the audio over the network so any computer with access to a browser/shell could listen.

Is anything like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

XBMC has many web based control plugins that are safe and only require that you traverse to the IP of the machine. (Second Scenario's solution)

In fact one is installed by default, goto the ip with port 8080 (:8080)

Again for the first scenario i have to say look into the plugins that come with xbmc standard. That is how I had my house running these.

Comment: I do use the web interface to control XBMC, but it doesn't allow me to stream content through the web interface though. Unless I'm missing your point.

Comment: There are some that allow the streaming of your content from server to client.